# How to install GUI apps in one language and CLI tools in other language?

Tags: language-support, system-language

I want to have my desktop with GUI applications in spanish, but I really prefer to have the CLI tools in english. Is there a way to do that?

My current workaround is using everything in english. That is ok for me, but not for other people using the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using bash, you can open `~/.bashrc` for editing and add the line:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US
```

Comment: If you want other localization settings (date format, decimal number format, currency format, etc), to be changed to English as well, you must also add the line `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`